# SUM query...once again having trouble with

Tags: sql

So I've asked a question like this before, and I guess I just didn't understand the answer (although the answer worked) to input the answer into this next problem

Easy query. I'm pulling employee, date, totalhrs. out of a timecard program PER employee. What i'm looking for is a sum of totalhrs colum but also to display ALL the timecard's submitted. So the code I use now

```
 SELECT date,totalhrs,SUM(totalhrs) 
 FROM tcardsubmit 
 WHERE employee= 'employee name' 
 ORDER BY date
```

This code displays

```
|EMPLOYEE | DATE        | TOTALHRS | SUM(TOTALHRS)
| myname  | myfirstdate |     5    |     10
```

What I want it to display is ALL the timecards that a specific employee has entered. Not JUST the one link. So in 'myname' I would have 3 timecards where the SUM does in fact equal 10 hours submitted for the week. The sum works for the math. I just can't seem to get it to display all the timecards that employee has entered. Here is what I want it to look like

```
|EMPLOYEE | DATE         | TOTALHRS | SUM(TOTALHRS)
| myname  | myfirstdate  |     5    |     10
| myname  | myseconddate |     4    |     10
| myname  | mythirddate  |     1    |     10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this and see if this works for you:

```
SELECT 
    date, 
    totalhrs, 
    (SELECT SUM(b.totalhrs) FROM tcardsubmit b WHERE b.employee = a.employee) AS totalhrs_sum 
FROM 
    tcardsubmit a 
WHERE 
    employee = 'employee name' 
ORDER BY 
    date
```

**Explanation For where clause in sub select:**
In the sub select WHERE clause, we are checking to get just the records that have same employee as the main select employee (b.employee = a.employee) so the SUM(b.totalhrs) would be only sum of records for the employee you are getting his records. In main select we say FROM tcardsubmit a so we name the main tcardsubmit a and in the sub select we name the table b to avoid any conflicts because of using same table and field names.

Comment: Works like a charm! Explanation to the WHERE clause?

Comment: @ldiggins You need to make sure that the sum inside the subselect matches the employee row on the outside that it will be matched with.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand b.employee = a.employee

Comment: @ldiggins In the sub select WHERE clause, we are checking to get just the records that have same employee as the main select employee (`b.employee = a.employee`) so the `SUM(b.totalhrs)` would be only sum of records for the employee you are getting his records. In main select we say `FROM tcardsubmit a` so we name the main tcardsubmit a and in the sub select we name the table b to avoid any conflicts because of using same table and field names.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to use a subquery to get the total hours in addition to the normal rows you are pulling back:

```
SELECT 
    date,
    totalhrs,
    (
    select 
        sum(a.totalhrs) 
    from 
        tcardsubmit a 
    where 
        a.employee=employee
    ) as TotalHrs
FROM 
    tcardsubmit 
WHERE 
    employee= 'employee name' 
ORDER BY 
    date
```

Comment: This is wrong, what if he gets 2 records with same date and totalhrs? There would be 1 record for those 2 ...

Comment: @Night2 Yes, you are correct, I have updated my answer with a subquery to get the total for each employee.

Comment: Funny you mentioned that, because the employee i'm testing this on has two timecards submitted with the same date and the same total hrs. And that's exactly what happened with code

Comment: @Night2 +1 for your trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tcardsubmit.employee, date,tcardsubmit.totalhrs, SumTotal.totalhrs
FROM tcardsubmit 
WHERE employee= 'employee name' 
inner join ( Select Employee, Sum(totalhrs) as TotalHrs From tcardSubmit Group By Employee) as sumTotal
On Sumtotal.employee = tcardsubmit.employee
ORDER BY date
```

If you want an aggregate (Min, Max , sum etc) and the detail, then a join is the way to go.

PS what are you going to do if you have two employees with the same name!

Comment: The query actually pulls their ENTIRE name from a Employee db. This is actually being used on php. When they login there userid pulls their full name, I carry that name through $employee = $empfullname
This way I don't get a double up on two different names

Comment: @tony your SQL syntax is not correct, the `WHERE` clause is in the wrong place.

Comment: @ldiggins. Okay what if you have two employees who's ENTIRE name is the same? What are you doing, making some poor fool put "John Smith 2" in there? "John Smith with the side parting", maybe. Give me a break.

Comment: lol. Well lets hope I don't get a lot of John Smith's working for me!  We only have 10 employee's so i'll put a note to the boss saying that no two employee's with the same name are allowed to work for him. The DB is setup nice actually for these causes. They don't enter there full name, just a username and pw upon signing in, and the php script pulls all the data out for them based on that.